# Creating object from CSV

Tags: c#, string

How can I create C# object from a CSV in single string as input?

For example if I have string as `string fields = "Id,Name,Code"`

All should be string type and default value should be string empty.

Comment: Welcome to SO, what have you tried so far? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . This is a good place to start: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ExpandoObject to create.

Updated My answer with Code :

```
   public object createDynamicObjectWithProperty(string fields)
  {
    var reqFields=fields.split(',');
    dynamic returnObj = new ExpandoObject();
     foreach(var propertiesName in reqFields)
      {

      AddProperty(returnObj,propertiesName,string.empty);
       } 
    return returnObj ;

}


    public static void AddProperty(ExpandoObject expando, string propertyName, object propertyValue)
     {
            //Take use of the IDictionary implementation
            var expandoDict = expando as IDictionary;
            if (expandoDict.ContainsKey(propertyName))
                expandoDict[propertyName] = propertyValue;
            else
                expandoDict.Add(propertyName, propertyValue);
       }
```