# Returning API result as dynamic object

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I want to return dynamic object from API and that object only have properties which will be passed in url as comma seperated

> e.g  API Call URL:
>
> api/Employee?Name,Age

should return
Json as

```
         {
         "Name":"Emp1",
         "Age":20
         }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Return an object, anonymous type, dictionary? What you posted is a JSON string, not a comma-separated value. By default, anything returned by a Web API is serialized into JSON

Comment: How dynamic do you want the dynamic operation to be? If you only want to return a subset of properties, you can add `JsonIgnore` attributes to the properties you don't wan't to return.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to reinvent the [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/learn/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ExpandoObject and reflection to create your dynamic retun object

Refer this answer
[Creating object from CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60302759/creating-object-from-csv/60302766#60302766)

Comment: Thanks @zeeCode will try this

Comment: Why this when you can just use a dictionary? I'd stay away from this if I were you.